# Infinite scroll codes doesn't work in my Angular project

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make my home page load more item by changing the API's url. Index must increase when the user scroll down to bottom of the page. This is my homepage's JS file `Haberler.js` :

```
angular.module('home', ['infinite-scroll'])
.controller('anasayfa', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {

      $scope.method = 'GET';

  $scope.loadMore = function () {
      if (this.busy) return;
          this.busy = true;
          $http.jsonp($scope.url).success(function (index) {
              for (var index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
                  $scope.url = 'http://api.donanimhaber.com/api/v1/site/NewsSite?pageIndex=' + index + '&pageSize=15';
              }
              this.busy = false;
          }.bind(this));

  }

      $scope.code = null;
      $scope.response = null;

      $http({ method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url }).
        then(function (response) {
            $scope.status = response.status;
            $scope.data = response.data.Data;
        }, function (response) {
            $scope.data = response.data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = response.status;
        });

  }]);
```

Th is the `.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="home">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="anasayfa">
    <div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
        <div ng-repeat="d in data">
            <div>
            <p >{{d.Title}}</p>
            <a href="/detay{{d.Url}}"><img class="image" src="{{d.Image}}" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ngInfiniteScroll/1.2.2/ng-infinite-scroll.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/Haberler.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work and since I'm very new at javascript and AngularJS I can't find out why. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The infinte-scroll directive is looking for a `loadmore` function on the scope to be called.

```
<div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="1">
```

But there is no such function defined on scope in your controller.

Try to define a function like this in your controller:

```
$scope.loadMore = function(){
   alert('infinte scroll method called');
}
```

This method will fire when you will scroll.

Comment: I deleted the function at the end which starts as loadMore : function(response) and added it separetely as you said. But now my homepage doesn't show anything, just a blank page. I edited the original question to show you what I tried. error is `angular.min.js:117 Error: [$http:badreq]`

Comment: You can keep your current code. Just add one more function as $scope.loadmore and try if infinte scroll is working or not

Comment: I tried, When I open the page it alerts, and also when I go to the bottom of the page i alerts twice. But nothing else changes, It doesn't load more images

Comment: That means infinte scroll is now working for you. You just need to change your logic now inside loadmore function

Comment: that's the part I couldn't do actually. Can you help a little?

Comment: I dnt know what your API return. But I would copy the same HTTP request in the load more function

Comment: And then append the response to current data.